Honeywell water Heater with no Green LED
Last week I did a water heater flush and immediately after I get no green LED to indicate that power is present.
I can get a pilot light lit (but it will not stay lit once I release the button) and a millivolt reading round 750.
I thought it was the motherboard so swapped that out and still no green light.
I also tested the gas valves and they do engage when given power from a 9 volt.
I think the only remaining thing is the thermostat?
WV8840A1000.
Please help!

could it be the LED failed ?

air in the gas line ?
